# Mock Class within an Class- Using the original behavior of these Classes when calling methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mockito, spy

I am having an issue with Null Pointer while trying to use Mockito with UT

```java
ServiceClass{
    @Inject
    private UtilsOne;
...
    public void methodOne(object1, object2, List<> elements){
       --- some logic ---
       UtilsOne.method1();
       --- some logic ---
       UtilsOne.method2();
       --- some logic ---
       Element e = UtilsOne.createElement(type,id);
       elements.add(e);
    }
...
}

UtilsOne{
    @Inject
    private UtilsTwo;
...
    public void method1(){
       --- some logic ---
    }
    public void method2(){
       --- some logic ---
    }
    public Element createElement(Object type, String id){
       --- some logic ---
       UtilsTwo.callMethod(type, id);
    }
...
}
```

This is how the structure of the classes looks in general.

I used `@InjectMocks` on the `ServiceClass` and `@Spy` on the `UtilsOne` so far the functionality worked for me, when calling `methodOne`, everything seems to work as expected but,

inside `methodOne` when reaching the `UtilsTwo.callMethod()` it throw a Null Pointer exception, I tried to figure out how to make the class (UtilsTwo) not Null so it will work but I did not figure it out.

If something is not clear please tell me I will edit and explain it better
Thanks in advance.

***Edited

After reading the answer I made it clearer, I want to check the content of the `List<> elements`, each Utils is has its own method and they have a connection - it will not be right to change the structure as it is now

Comment: Which class are you actually trying to test? `ServiceClass`?

Comment: Yes, the other classes I test separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot trial and error, I used `ReflectionTestUtils` and it solved my problems

This is the general structure
`ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ClassWhereTheFieldIsAt, "NameOfFieldInClass", NameOfFieldInTest);`

in the test class if it looks like this

```
@Spy 
private UtilsOne utilsOne;

private UtilsTwo utilsTwo;
@Test 
public void testElements(){
   ReflectionTestUtils.setField(utilsOne, "utilsTwo", utilsTwo);

....
}
```

For me the the `NameOfFieldInClass` and `NameOfFieldInTest` are the same.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should only mock the direct dependencies of the class you're testing, not the dependencies of the decencies. In your example, if you are testing `ServiceClass`, you should just mock `UtilsOne`, not `UtilsTwo`. So inject a mock of `UtilsOne` into `ServiceClass` and mock the response of `method3()` - that way no reference to `UtilsTwo` is ever made.

You might also want to test that `UtilsOne.method3()` is working correctly and interacting with `UtilsTwo` as you expect, but that should be a totally separate set of tests, where you mock `UtilsTwo` injected into. a real instance of `UtilsOne`.

Comment: I want to verify that I understand correctly.
in practice what you're saying is that I should use 

`@InjectMocks`
`ServiceClass`


`@Mock`
`UtilsOne`

`Mockito.when(UnitsOne.method1()).thenReturn(...)`

Comment: Basically, yes.